# Can I compile an iOS static library from Windows/Linux

Tags: c++, ios, static, .a

I have C++ code, which I have managed to compile into an iOS static library ("library.a") using Xcode. I am then including this in my project (Xamarin.iOS, though this shouldn't matter) and have managed to get it working as expected. The code is c/c++ and doesn't reference any code from the iOSFrameworks. I was wondering if it would be possible to find a way to build this (just compile the library) without a mac computer.

Something like download the clang compiler on a windows machine and then build an "library.a" that is compatible with the arm architectures and thus will work if I include it in my iOS project.

I have tried doing some reading on the web which suggests that it wouldn't work, but they might not be working in my exact circumstances etc.

The reason behind my need for this is because the C++ part of the code base is maintained by someone else, and we require them to build the iOS compatible library without us having access to their code. They do not have access to a Mac.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Cross compiling is theoretically possible and it works very well for open plattforms. Unfortunately everything made by Apple is very, very closed down. The GCC fork made by Apple is as open as it gets, thanks to the GPL. But without having the platform libraries available as well, you're SOL.